# Problem in moving cpt's from local website to live website

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I've made a custom post type, designed a custom page template for it and tested it on the local server. I've copied those custom post types to my live website.
On live website it is pulling custom fields but not picking up that CSS.

Comment: How do you include your css? Are you sure is not loaded or just overwritten?

Comment: I replaced the css file in child theme with my file

Comment: Ctrl(Cmd)+Shift+R in the browser. Does it help?